# Web Scraping Using data-title and Without Using Classes or Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website the issue is that the specific elements do not have Classes or Ids, but they do have data-tile. I need help referring to these when I am choosing an element to scrape.

Here is the html that I am scraping.

```
    <div data-v-1234567z="">
    <table data-v-1234567z="" align="center">
        <thead data-v-1234567z="">
            <tr data-v-1234567z="">
                <th data-v-1234567z="">User</th>
                <th data-v-1234567z="" style="cursor: pointer;">Money</th>
                <th data-v-1234567z="" style="cursor: pointer;">Watch Time (minutes)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-v-1234567z="">
            <tr data-v-1234567z="">
                <td data-v-1234567z="" data-title="User" class="user-cell">
                    <span data-v-821a25a2="" data-v-1234567z="" class="mini-user-display">
                        <img data-v-821a25a2="" src="https://image.com" class="mini-user-profile-image" />
                        <span data-v-821a25a2="" class="mini-user-name">user1234</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td data-v-1234567z="" data-title="Money">100,000</td>
                <td data-v-1234567z="" data-title="WatchTime">678</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to scrape the Money, WatchTime, and username.

Here is the code that I am using for the scraper.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {

    const $ = context.jQuery;

    const results = [];
    $('tbody').each(function() {
        results.push({
            userName: $(this).find(".mini-user-name").text(),
            watchTime: $(this).find("data-title-watchTime").text()
        });
    });
    return results;
}
```

There are many issues with this code the userName actually does return the usernames the issue is that there is no break in between all the names and it's just one big blob.
The other bigger issue is that I can't get any data back from watchTime, this is because I can't figure out how to properly select the WatchTime data-title in JavaScript.

I have looked for a few hours and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an element by data-attribute in JQuery you just call it like you would in CSS, watchTime in your case would be called like this:

```
watchTime: $(this).find('[data-title="WatchTime"]').text()
```

As for your code coming out as one blob you are pushing objects to an array, until you do something to iterate over your array of objects and convert them to a readable format it will just be a blob of data. Without seeing what is calling this function and how you're handling the returned data it's impossible to provide much assistance with that.

EDIT:
Here's an example of how you might want to return your data using template literals for a more readable output.

```
const results = [];

$('tbody').each(function() {
  results.push(
`Username: ${$(this).find(".mini-user-name").text()}
WatchTime: ${$(this).find('[data-title="WatchTime"]').text()}
Money: ${$(this).find('[data-title="Money"]').text()}`
  );
});

return results;
```

This would give an output like:

Username: user1234

WatchTime: 678

Money: 100,000

Comment: That worked for getting watch time new issues have arrived though. The data that it's outputting has a comma at random places and it's also a blob. I am doing nothing than what you see here. I am running this on apify they handle the actual scraping. If you have any idea on how I can make each username and watch time output as its own row that would be great.

Comment: Never used apify but if what you need is the output to be formatted then you don't want to return an object. An object is great if you are taking the data and doing something with it on the other side since it allows you to keep key-value pairs. What you might want to do instead is return a string formatted for your needs. Template literals would be a good solution for that, I updated my answer to include a formatted way of outputting the data.